# JavaScript check variable globally

Tags: javascript, html

I want the global variable `exp`, when it's 100, to increase the level. I'm using a button to take `exp`.
It works fine. It gives `exp` and one other variable. But the level doesn't increment by 1 when `exp` is 100.

```
exp = 0;
level = 1;
```

250 lines of code later, I have this:

```
if (exp == 100) {
  level = level + 1;
  exp = 0;
  document.getElementById("level").innerHTML = level;
  document.getElementById("exp").innerHTML = exp;
}
```

It doesn't work. After 100, it keeps counting.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Without seeing the rest of your code, we can't give you a definitive answer.  All we can do is guess.

Comment: add var to llevel = 1; and replase level=level+1; to level++; because level=level+1;  override variable.

Comment: Try writing `>=` instead of `==`. That should catch it if it never equals exactly 100.

Comment: nothing worked.still counts over 100.

Comment: There are several things that could cause this -- everything from `exp` being redefined somewhere to scoping issues.  Use JSLint or JSHint to check for many common programming mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to say what's wrong because you haven't included enough code here.

However, it appears that there are a couple of things that could be wrong:

1. Where have you defined `exp` and `level`? You haven't used `var` to define them above, which means that you have likely defined them somewhere else and are *re*-defining here, which would reset the count each time it increments, defeating the purpose of the incrementation.
2. What causes the incrementation to occur? Have you wrapped your `if` statement in the function you're calling to increment `exp`? If not, you may only be checking it the first time, which would cause it to never trigger the statement.

I've created a demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/AstroCB/4120c2u8/) that fills in some of these holes and it works fine in isolation. The question, of course, is how that piece fits within the context of your code. The solution to that requires a bit more information about how you have your project set up.